# ArcGIS Online scene viewer not displaying features

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d

I am creating a few online scenes using ArcGIS online. To this end I have several different feature files that were multipatches but are now exported as a web layer. The export was done using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.1. The total scene I am trying to open conforms to all limitations I know of, mainly being less than 2000 points.

There are two features, [this one](https://arcg.is/0LGLXH) was created at the end of March and displays fine when opened in an online scene. [This one](https://arcg.is/1uvibv) was created today and will not open in an online scene. I made both of them in the same way so far as I can remember. I am looking for any advice as to what I have done differently and how I may correct my workflow, as I have several other features to convert.

UPDATES:

-The features that work, when viewed in a local online scene, do not display the option for a texture. The features that do not work, do display the option for a texture

-Both files can be opened and viewed in an online map, just not in a scene

- SD file for the feature that does work is [here](https://arcg.is/1jDOzi). The SD file for the feature that does not work is [here](https://arcg.is/0bLKiG).

Comment: just an FYI scene viewer no longer has any # of feature limitations on all point lines and polygons from feature layers. Scene Layers never had this limitation. When loading the layer I see this error in the console: [esri.layers.graphics.controllers.I3SOnDemandController] Failed to load node '1': [TypeError]: Cannot read property 'strideIdx' of undefined. Can you share the SD file generated when being published?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure how to get the SD file with my current permissions. I have an educational licence for the software which is managed at a central level.

Comment: The SD file or FGDB that should exist on My Content that was used to publish the feature layer.

Comment: Beg your pardon here. I've added SD links to the files in the main question.

Comment: Not sure if something happened during the publishing process but can you delete the feature layer and scene layer from the not working case and publish from the SD file above. I was able to publish from the "does not work SD" through the Online UI.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with this, that last suggestion worked. I deleted the feature layer and scene layer that were created when exported from ArcGIS Pro. Then published it though the SD as suggested. Once published I published it again from the new feature layer as a scene layer, and that file displays perfectly. Thank you again!